# frozen numeric arrays, dataclasses, numba

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I am trying to improve quality of an existing scientific code by declaring classes as dataclasses, declaring them as `frozen=True` as much as possible. One of the intents is to use numba's JIT for acceleration at a few places.

The code is currently using tuples for storing small constant numeric arrays (think of constant 3d coordinate), but tuples don't declare their size, can't be easily consumed by numba and don't support basic arithmetics. Numpy arrays, on the other hand, are dynamically-sized and modifiable, not lending themselves to frozen dataclasses easily.

I am looking for suitable class for fixed-size frozen numeric array which supports basic arithmetics and could be used with numba's JIT (with `nopython=True`) without further conversions. Any tips?

Comment: I would use numpy arrays for this.  If you really want, define a class with `@property` (but not `@property` setter) that references the array, but I can't imagine that would be worth the overhead.

Comment: also, if you haven't used JIT before - give it a test run early.  I did not see the performance improvement I expected from JIT

Comment: I don't see the connection between using `dataclass` and `numba`.

Comment: Numpy arrays are as dynamically-sized as tuples. Resize or concatenate functions produce new arrays instead of modifying the originals. On the other hand, you can declare an array `a` to be immutable using `a.flags.writeable = False`. This helps when an API user passes an array to a function and also attempts to modify it in a different place.